# Retrieve values of checked list items

Tags: android, xamarin

i was following an example i saw online to retrieve checked items
but in the example it only retrieves one value

```
int len = listview.Count;
            SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listview.CheckedItemPositions;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                if (checkedItems.Get(i))
                {
                    string item = list[i];
                    /* do whatever you want with the checked item */                        
                    txt.Text = item;                        
                }
```

So how do i Retrieve all of the checked items values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a data structure of some sort

```
        List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();

        int len = listview.Count;
        SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = 
        listview.CheckedItemPositions;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            if (checkedItems.Get(i))
            {
                checkedItems.Add(list[i]);
            }
```